# What is the syntax for filtering Logcat with multiple tags in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

When filtering LogCat in Android Studio's "Android Device Monitor", what is the syntax that should be used for multiple tags?

For example, i would like to view all logcat occurences tagged as either "foo" or "bar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one `|` character to delimit your tags:

E.g.: `tag1|tag2|...|tagN`

Worked for me in this version of the Android Device Monitor:

[image]

Comment: what's the difference in results?

Comment: Yours doesn't work for me at all. In my case, I assume your answer created "foo||bar" as a tag, as opposed to the intended "foo" OR "bar". Note that the Device Monitor I use is the .exe that comes with the Android SDK in /tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/. There might be differences in the implementation to the one you use.

Comment: spot on.  removed (my own) accepted answer, in favor of yours.  Made minor edits to remove references to previously accepted answer (which does not exist anymore).  I would find it courteous if you would accept said edit, upon which answer acceptability isnt contingent,of course.

Comment: I would gladly accept your edit, but there seems to be no option for me to do that.

Comment: seems like the edit was accepted.  :)